# mix-blend-mode применяется относительно родительского элемента

Tags: html, css

есть фиксированная шапка сайта с ссылками, им я хочу задать такой же цвет как background текущей секции.mix-blend-mode устанавливает такой же цвет как у шапки секции

```
<header class="header">
    <a href="#" class="header__logo">LOGO</a>
    <nav class="header__nav">
        <ul class="header__menu">
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">HERO</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">CONTENT</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">SLIDER</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">FOOTER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Подскажите как можно это реализовать